# Image tiff in Gmap.net

Tags: c#, tiff, geotiff, gmap.net

I have a TIFF image which contains geographic data (UTM coordinates and scale), this data and the extracts using the LibTiff library, I need to load this image on a map of Gmap.net in the coordinates and the corresponding scale. Does anyone know how to do this or if this is possible on Gmap.net?

Comment: Try searching for a SVG editor which creates map layers so you can put an image on one layer the add text to other layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add image on Gmap.net:

```
   GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
   GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(
   new PointLatLng(48.8617774, 2.349272),
   new Bitmap("mybitmap.jpg"));
   //add markers in 0 position prevent the superposition whit another markers, MainMap = map of GMap.net
   MainMap.Overlays.Insert(0, markers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmap doesn't allow 2 layer to put on top of each other if you are using versiın 1.7.5.
Which GMap version do you use?

Comment: I have version 1.7.5 of gmap.net installed, is it possible to add one layer on top of another in other versions, how do I do it?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not use any version other than 1.7.5.  There is another branch of GMap.net which has a version of 1.9.9 but when I looked the version details I could not find any development about multiple layers.